# ADO.net: Why is the connection pool not using the already opened connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, ado.net, connection-pooling

the expected behaviour with this code would be that one connection gets opened. Then the connection is returned into the connection pool and reused on the second open(). Right?

But when I execute this code against **SQL Server 2005** the second open() turns the transaction into an distributed transaction. I see from this moment on 2 connections on the server. And the second open() takes around 3-4 seconds. From this point on only the second is used. The first connection seems to be boken somehow.

With **SQL Server 2008 R2** only one connection is used, as expected.

Any ideas? Thank you!

```
using (var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{

    var constring = @"Server=xxx;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=10;";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Lightweight Transaction Manager" (LTM) support didn't exist for SQL Server 2005 - it doesn't support promotable transactions of this kind, so in order to make the guarantees required for a `TransactionScope`, it has to use a full "Distributed Transaction Coordinator" (DTC) transaction - and it has to do it pretty much immediately, if there is an ambient transaction (`TransactionScope`).

When the backend server supoorts promotable transactions, it allows the LTM to *not do this*, and instead use a LTM transaction that can be *promoted* to DTC *as and when required*. Which will be "never" in most cases that don't span multiple different resources in a single `TransactionScope`.

This means that SQL Server 2005 combined with `TransactionScope` has to do a lot more work, leading to this kind of result.

Since end-of-life (end of "extended support") for SQL Server 2005 was April 12, 2016 - this really shouldn't hurt anyone today. SQL Server 2008 R2 has until July 9, 2019.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for your answer. I read about LTM and transaction promotion. If I unterstand it correct, your answer explains why the transaction gets promoted because a second connection is opened. But why is a second connection opened at all? Why is the first connection not used? Thanks!

Comment: @vlopel all I've got there is "because reasons"